# Show properties on new profile page in SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-property

Microsoft recently replaced the default profile page, person.aspx, to personimmersive.aspx in SharePoint Online. After this I no longer can decide which properties that will show up on the profile for the user. Usually it was just to select "Show in the profile properties section of the user's profile page" and the property would show up in the profile page. Can anyone else replicate or is it just me that having a bad Monday?

Comment: We are facing a similar issue where our existing profile fields are no more visible after this change. Did you find any resolution to this? We have taken it up with MS support, however we haven't got a resolution on this. Kind Regards.

Comment: The reason is that the Profile Info web part is removed. A solution can be to export that web part (dwp) from an on premise installation and add it to the page but it's an ugly solution. Maybe the best way is to make an app that can expose custom properties in an app part.

Comment: Yes, this is an appalling change. We've made good use of the profile properties and now users cannot see them! I'm working on a JSOM script that can be added to the profile page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,You can decide which properties  will show up on the profile for the user.
The issue on the new personimmersive.aspx page has been resolved. When accessing this page, you can click MORE INFORMATION to display additional properties.
Refer:http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/238397.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It seems that someone at least in Microsoft agrees with my sentiment that it was an appalling change because the change has now been undone!

The "About" section appears in the right-hand column again of our tenancy. For reference, the information shown is controlled by editing the user properties in the SharePoint Admin site.

It looks like the PersonImmersive page is still changing since I now get an error if I try (with global admin privalages) to edit the page. A few weeks ago when the change you mentioned happened, I could still edit part of the page. The change to the Organisation Browser on that page has also changed again!